# Law of the Seven Degrees of Separation

Tags: graph-theory, demography

I would like to know whether any empirical studies have been conducted on the so-called "Law of the Seven Degrees of Separation", a statement that any two people in the world are separated by at most seven connections connecting one person (acquaintance, friend, relative, or other) to another.

I wonder whether any statistical data is available on this (presumably it's just hype, but I would really like to know to what extent this is true, and what the data says with respect to this matter).

Comment: I always heard that it was [*six* degrees of separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation). For instance all American actors are supposedly 6 degrees from [Kevin Bacon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Degrees_of_Kevin_Bacon). There was also a [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108149/) made about the concept, which I remember liking at the time. However, it isn't clear that your question has anything to do w/ statistics. If it does, can you clarify that / how it is on-topic here?

Comment: @gung It is actually very difficult to find film actors who are more than *2* degrees of separation from Kevin Bacon! **Aside:** not sure I agree that the OP's question is opinion based (for the VTC who commented that way, whoever that was). The question could doubtlessly be improved by tweaking to ask about statistical *methods* to evaluate the claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept is called the small world phenomenon. I am not sure what you mean by statistical data. If you are looking for an introduction and some introductory work see

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/networks-book-ch20.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there have been studies on online social networks (Facebook and Twitter) that show that two random users are connected are at an average distance of 4.7 hops (which means an average of 3.7 degrees of separation).

Some pair of users, however, may be more distant, or even not connected at all.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation

Answer (score 1):

The original study on that matter is this one:

Travers, Jeffrey & Stanley Milgram. 1969. "An Experimental Study of the Small World Problem." Sociometry, Vol. 32, No. 4, pp. 425-443

(also see Wikipedia link posted by @Antonio)